# Make Handsontable autocomplete popup wider than the column

Tags: handsontable

The Customer ID column is setup to use autocomplete. The autocomplete values concatenates various customer information together, to aid the user in selecting the correct one. Once selected, the Customer ID is put into the grid.

I cannot figure out how to make the autocomplete popup wider so that it fits the concatenated information.

[image: autocomplete values cutoff]

This is what it needs to look like, which I achieved by tinkering with the elements after they were rendered. Ideally, it would be just wide enough to fit the content.

[image: autocomplete values not cutoff]

Comment: Hi @Matt Slavicek I know its been a while, but how did you get the autocomplete to show you all that data in the choices?

Answer (score 0):

Try using select2-editor from
https://github.com/trebuchetty/Handsontable-select2-editor

The select2 editor automatically expands to the width of the column text.

[image]